# No module named 'flask_mysqldb'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un programa en python donde utilizo las librerias de flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL,MySQLdb
```

Estoy ejecutando el programa en Linux, intento hacer una conexión a la base de datos la cual utilizo para realizar un login en una aplicación que estoy realizando, y al momento de hacerlo me arroja el siguiente error:

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
ImportError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'
```

He intentado con esto pip install flask-MySQLdb pero continua sin funcionar, incluso ya he desinstalado e instalado nuevamente y no funciona aun.

**Este es mi código:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL,MySQLdb

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
server.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
server.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
server.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '1234'
server.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'MeshliumDB'

mysql = MySQL(server)
```

**Método login:**

```
@server.route('/login',methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        password = request.form['password'].encode('utf-8')

        curl = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        curl.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=%s",(name,))
        user = curl.fetchone()
        curl.close()
```

Cuando corro el programa en Windows va bien, cuando lo intento correr en ubuntu es cuando surge el problema.
Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto?.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Saludos puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)
```

**Actualización:**

Otra forma de conectar y definir tus credenciales a MYSQL serian:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)
```

Donde **app** lo podrias definir asi:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'usuario'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'clave'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'miBase'
```

Quedaria algo asi:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
    from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

    mysql = MySQL()
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
    app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'usuario'
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'clave'
    app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'miBase'
    mysql.init_app(app)

    cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()

    @app.route('/')
   def someName():
     sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla"
     cursor.execute(sql)
     results = cursor.fetchall()
     return render_template('pagina.html', result=results)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Fuentes:**

[Mysql Flask Documentacion Oficial](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Ahora me arroja este error: "curl = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'connection'", la linea del codigo donde me lo arroja es este: " curl = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)" al momento de iniciar sesion, sabes cual podría ser el error?

Comment: podrias agregar mas tu codigo para ver como lo tienes y poder darte una mejor respuesta porque la parecer tambien estas haciendo una conexion y x ello el error editar tu pregunta aqui ==> [edit] <==

Comment: He puesto el codigo tal y como tu lo tienes y ahora me arroja este error:  "pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'Usuario'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")". He checado los datos de conexión y están correctos.